NATS Elixir Client: Operations on KV store doesn't work
I have the coordinates KV bucket in NGS Cloud. I mirrored that bucket to my leaf node dev
When I try to put and get KV keys using nats cli, it works fine.
However, I keep getting no message found for get and :timeout for put operations on KV using nats.ex Elixir library.


nats context info

NATS Configuration Context "gtg-local"

  Server URLs: nats://127.0.0.1:4222
         Path: /Users/munjalapatel/.config/nats/context/gtg-local.json


nats kv ls

╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                Key-Value Buckets                               │
├─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────────┤
│ Bucket      │ Description │ Created             │ Size  │ Values │ Last Update │
├─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────────┤
│ coordinates │             │ 2024-07-20 09:52:59 │ 100 B │ 1      │ 7m15s       │
╰─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────────╯


nats s ls -a

╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                        Streams                                       │
├────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────┬──────────────┤
│ Name           │ Description │ Created             │ Messages │ Size  │ Last Message │
├────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────────┤
│ KV_coordinates │             │ 2024-07-20 09:52:59 │ 1        │ 100 B │ 8m5s         │
╰────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┴──────────────╯


PUT Operation
Trace using nats cli

nats kv put coordinates "33d00533601518134-m117d06731438930926.id" "na.us.ca.san-diego.san-diego" --trace

10:11:49 >>> $JS.API.STREAM.INFO.KV_coordinates


10:11:49 <<< $JS.API.STREAM.INFO.KV_coordinates: {"type":"io.nats.jetstream.api.v1.stream_info_response","total":0,"offset":0,"limit":0,"config":{"name":"KV_coordinates","retention":"limits","max_consumers":-1,"max_msgs":-1,"max_bytes":-1,"max_age":0,"max_msgs_per_subject":1,"max_msg_size":-1,"discard":"new","storage":"memory","num_replicas":1,"duplicate_window":120000000000,"placement":{},"mirror":{"name":"KV_coordinates","external":{"api":"$JS.ngs.API","deliver":""}},"compression":"none","allow_direct":true,"mirror_direct":true,"sealed":false,"deny_delete":true,"deny_purge":false,"allow_rollup_hdrs":true,"consumer_limits":{}},"created":"2024-07-20T16:52:59.765798Z","state":{"messages":1,"bytes":100,"first_seq":1,"first_ts":"2024-07-20T17:00:21.261461449Z","last_seq":1,"last_ts":"2024-07-20T17:00:21.261461449Z","num_subjects":1,"consumer_count":0},"cluster":{"name":"dev","leader":"dev"},"mirror":{"name":"KV_coordinates","external":{"api":"$JS.ngs.API","deliver":""},"lag":0,"active":841691000},"ts":"2024-07-20T17:11:49.390147Z"}
na.us.ca.san-diego.san-diego

Trace using this library

:ok = KV.put_value(:gnat, "coordinates", "#{key}.id", id)

│ !!! REQ
│ %{
│   body: "na.us.ca.san-diego.san-diego",
│   topic: "$KV.coordinates.33d005376074881035-m117d0675056841886.id",
│   recipient: #PID<0.854.0>
│ }
│ ---
│ !!! SUB
│ "_INBOX.PpTLlRUldV4e6CTK.0IYlNCdIOtX1JaQd"
│ ---
│ !!! RES
│ {:error, :timeout}


GET Operation
Trace using nats cli

nats kv get coordinates "33d00533601518134-m117d06731438930926.id" --trace

10:17:19 >>> $JS.API.STREAM.INFO.KV_coordinates


10:17:19 <<< $JS.API.STREAM.INFO.KV_coordinates: {"type":"io.nats.jetstream.api.v1.stream_info_response","total":0,"offset":0,"limit":0,"config":{"name":"KV_coordinates","retention":"limits","max_consumers":-1,"max_msgs":-1,"max_bytes":-1,"max_age":0,"max_msgs_per_subject":1,"max_msg_size":-1,"discard":"new","storage":"memory","num_replicas":1,"duplicate_window":120000000000,"placement":{},"mirror":{"name":"KV_coordinates","external":{"api":"$JS.ngs.API","deliver":""}},"compression":"none","allow_direct":true,"mirror_direct":true,"sealed":false,"deny_delete":true,"deny_purge":false,"allow_rollup_hdrs":true,"consumer_limits":{}},"created":"2024-07-20T16:52:59.765798Z","state":{"messages":1,"bytes":100,"first_seq":2,"first_ts":"2024-07-20T17:11:49.470524286Z","last_seq":2,"last_ts":"2024-07-20T17:11:49.470524286Z","num_subjects":1,"consumer_count":0},"cluster":{"name":"dev","leader":"dev"},"mirror":{"name":"KV_coordinates","external":{"api":"$JS.ngs.API","deliver":""},"lag":0,"active":303980000},"ts":"2024-07-20T17:17:19.958569Z"}
10:17:19 >>> $JS.API.DIRECT.GET.KV_coordinates.$KV.coordinates.33d00533601518134-m117d06731438930926.id


10:17:19 <<< $JS.API.DIRECT.GET.KV_coordinates.$KV.coordinates.33d00533601518134-m117d06731438930926.id: na.us.ca.san-diego.san-diego
coordinates > 33d00533601518134-m117d06731438930926.id revision: 2 created @ 20 Jul 24 17:11 UTC

na.us.ca.san-diego.san-diego

Trace using this library

KV.get_value(:gnat, "coordinates", "#{key}.id")

│ !!! REQ
│ %{
│   body: "{\"last_by_subj\":\"$KV.coordinates.33d005376074881035-m117d0675056841886.id\"}",
│   topic: "$JS.API.STREAM.MSG.GET.KV_coordinates",
│   recipient: #PID<0.854.0>
│ }
│ ---
│ !!! SUB
│ "_INBOX.PpTLlRUldV4e6CTK.xYhioQgY+h76NT1E"
│ ---
│ !!! RES
│ {:ok,
│  %{
│    body: "{\"type\":\"io.nats.jetstream.api.v1.stream_msg_get_response\",\"error\":{\"code\":404,\"err_code\":10037,\"description\":\"no message
│ found\"}}",
│    gnat: #PID<0.807.0>,
│    topic: "_INBOX.PpTLlRUldV4e6CTK.xYhioQgY+h76NT1E",
│    reply_to: nil
│  }}

